# LED blinking issue

Tags: programming

i made a distance measuring circuit with different led for different distance ranges

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define BPin 7
#define piezoPin 9
#define RPin 4
#define GPin 8

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(BPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(piezoPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;

  if (distance >= 200 || distance <= 0) {
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");
  }
  delay(1000);
  {
    if (distance <= 25 || distance <= 0) {
      digitalWrite(RPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(RPin, LOW);
    }
  }

  {
    if (distance >= 25 && distance <= 50) {
      digitalWrite(GPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(GPin, LOW);
    }

    {
      if (distance >= 50 && distance <= 75) {
        digitalWrite(GPin, HIGH);
      }
      else {
        digitalWrite(BPin, LOW);
      }

      {
        if (distance >= 75 && distance <= 100) {
          digitalWrite(BPin, HIGH);
        }
        else {
          digitalWrite(GPin, LOW);
          {
            {
              if (distance >= 100 && distance <= 200) {
                digitalWrite(piezoPin, HIGH);
              }
              else {
                digitalWrite(piezoPin, LOW);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

everything is working fine except Gpin it is blinking please  help me 
i am also uploading link to download my .ino file 
link; https://www.datafilehost.com/d/e19b35d5

Comment: First align your code (put { and } nicely under each other which belong together, also remove unneeded { and } (like around if statements). Also do not indent when it's not needed (e.g. the pin mode settings).

Comment: I formatted your code, and your logic is extremely convoluted, and I suspect also incorrect in several places. I counted at least 5 unnecessary brackets, and inconsistent if/else structure. Also if something is lower then 25 it's already lower then 0.

Comment: I guess it should be `if(distance blabla) digitalWrite(pinX,HIGH); else digitalWrite(pinX,LOW);` (you have different pins in if/else case). Also two leds will be on when `distance==50`, `distance==75` or `distance==100` which I would consider a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code without unnecessary brackets:

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define BPin 7
#define piezoPin 9
#define RPin 4
#define GPin 8

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(BPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(piezoPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;

  if (distance >= 200 || distance <= 0) {
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");
  }
  delay(1000);

  if (distance <= 25 || distance <= 0) {
    digitalWrite(RPin, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(RPin, LOW);
  }

  if (distance >= 25 && distance <= 50) {
    digitalWrite(GPin, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(GPin, LOW);
  }

  if (distance >= 50 && distance <= 75) {
    digitalWrite(GPin, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(BPin, LOW);
  }

  if (distance >= 75 && distance <= 100) {
    digitalWrite(BPin, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(GPin, LOW);
    if (distance >= 100 && distance <= 200) {
      digitalWrite(piezoPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {
      digitalWrite(piezoPin, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Using the ternary operator you can write some if statements easier:

```
#define trigPin 13
#define echoPin 12
#define BPin 7
#define piezoPin 9
#define RPin 4
#define GPin 8

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(BPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(piezoPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;

  if (distance >= 200 || distance <= 0) {
    Serial.println("Out of range");
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");
  }
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(RPin, (distance <= 25 || distance <= 0) ? HIGH : LOW);
  digitalWrite(GPin, (distance >= 25 && distance <= 50) ? HIGH : LOW);

  if (distance >= 50 && distance <= 75) {
    digitalWrite(GPin, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(BPin, LOW);
  }

  if (distance >= 75 && distance <= 100) {
    digitalWrite(BPin, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(GPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(piezoPin, (distance >= 100 && distance <= 200) ? HIGH : LOW);
  }
}
```

Some remarks to think about that helps you solve your sketch (and is the reason why your GPin may blink):

1. The line part `(distance <= 25 || distance <= 0)` can be rewritten to `(distance <= 25)` since if a value is less/equal than 0, it automatically is less/equal than 25.
2. You set based one a condition a pin to HIGH or another pin to LOW, I would expect both pins to change, or the same pin. But I don't know your requirements.
3. The 'edge' values (e.g. 25, 50, 75) fall in multiple conditions, you probably want to exclude the end edge. It is a sort of guideline to include the start and exclude the end, e.g. `if (distance >= 50) && (distance < 75)`.

In your case you probably are best of checking the distance like this:

```
if (distance < 0)
{
   ...
} 
else if (distance < 25)
{ 
   // 0 <= distance < 25)
   ...
}
else if (distance < 50)
{
   // 25 <= distance < 50)
}
...
```

or do it the other way around:

```
digitalWrite(GPin, 'condition in which GPin should be on' ? HIGH : LOW);
digitalWrite(BPin, 'condition in which BPin should be on' ? HIGH : LOW);
```

e.g. when you want the GPin to be on when between 0 and 25:

```
digitalWrite(GPin, ((distance >=0) && (distance < 25) ? HIGH : LOW);
```

Comment: I'm afraid your conclusion of point 1. is not correct. The first line is OK. But if a value is less or equal than 25 it is not automatically less then 0. e.g. the value 25 is less or equal then 25 but greater than 0. But the other direction is correct. I know, I count peas, it's my hobby ;-).

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I think I'm correct. If the distance is smaller than 0 it is always smaller than 25, thus the sub expression distance < 0 is unnecessary, as the range (-inifinit,0) is within the range of (-infinit, 25). If the operator would be an &&, than you would be correct.

Comment: Yes the formula you derived is correct, but you had written "since if a value is less/equal than 25, it automatically is less/equal than 0." And that is not correct.

Comment: Sorry perhaps the word "conclusion" irritates you, but I'm not a native English speaker. Perhaps I've misused it.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer No need to sorry, I just completely missed your point, I was focused on the formula, not the text. And you were right, so I fixed the answer. You didn't  irritate me at all, I just misinterpreted your text (I'm also not a native speaker). Thanks for your improvement, and I adapted my answer accordingly.